# What is the universal range of the user defined textScaleFactor in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, fonts, accessibility, font-size, flutter-layout

After my fruitless search for the expected range of the textScaleFactor parameter I attempted to answer my q by printing...

```
MediaQuery.textScaleFactorOf(context);
```

2 times while debugging on my Note 9: The output was 0.8 & 2 when I set the font size (in my accessibility settings) @ its min & max, resp..

My q is: Can I expect this to be the universal range across all devices?

If you're unsure, I would certainly accept an answer from someone posting their own test results (especially if they were to test on iphone).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the iOS simulator and my iPhoneXS Max the default is 1.0
Even when [Display View setting](https://9to5mac.com/2018/09/26/iphone-xs-max-display-zoom/) is Zoomed or Standard.

When I go to Accessibility and change the size to the max available size (step by step):

```
flutter: text scale 1.1176470588235294
flutter: text scale 1.2352941176470589
flutter: text scale 1.3529411764705883
```

If i check the toggle for the ["Larger Accessibility Sizes"](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202828), the max I get:

```
flutter: text scale 3.1176470588235294
```

Going down with the slider in Accessibility (only 3 steps available):

```
flutter: text scale 0.9411764705882353
flutter: text scale 0.8823529411764706
flutter: text scale 0.8235294117647058
```

I don't know how useful those values can be to you, but to answer your questions you SHOULD NOT expect min=0.8 & max=2 ...

In any case, if you need to constrain the factor somehow, as I don't know any way to inject them in the MediaQuery that MaterialApp uses, you should have a custom function that normalizes the MediaQuery.textScaleFactorOf(context), maybe at the root of your widget tree, and manually apply that to each Text::textScaleFactor ?

Comment: This was very helpful, ty! I would like to wait a couple of days to see if the current range (i.e., 0.8-3.118, after accounting for your results) can be extended any further by additional answers.

Answer (score 0):

Someone already provided a satisfactory answer to the question; this is just me expanding on their closing remarks:

> In any case, if you need to constrain the factor somehow, as I don't know any way to inject them in the MediaQuery that MaterialApp uses, you should have a custom function that normalizes the MediaQuery.textScaleFactorOf(context), maybe at the root of your widget tree, and manually apply that to each Text::textScaleFactor ?

I ended up using the following code to constrain textScaleFactor within 0.8-2.0; I added an extra constraint where the result will always be a multiple of 0.1:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';
import 'authentication-page.dart';

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      builder: (context, child) {
        onLayout(context);
        return MediaQuery(
            child: child,
            data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: max(0.8, min(2.0, (10*MediaQuery.textScaleFactorOf(context)).round()/10))));
      },
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: AuthenticationPage(),
    );
  }
}
```